# Why are avatars necessary when karma is supposed to balance out evil?

Tags: karma, avatars, kalki

Avatars, especially Kalki, is supposed to appear on Earth to battle evil and rid the world of adharma. Why is this necessary if karma already "guides" souls towards moksha?

I mean, if people are bad, they are judged by Yama and reborn as according to their karma, no? Doesn't that in and of itself hold "evil" in place?

Or am I misunderstanding either concept?

Answer (score -1):

jagadguru madvacharya has said that lord hari is an ocean of infinite auspicious qualities and he is free from all faults. lord hari is the ocean of infinite mercy. he is also a just judge. he is not partial to anyone. thats why every living entity gets the fruits of his or her karma. as per bhagvad gita there are 3 types of work as per( gita chapter 4 verse 17). 1. karma 2. vikarma 3. akarma. the works which are done as per the instructions of the scriptures are called karma which results to give rewards. the works which are against the instructions of scriptures are called vikarma which leads to punishments. the third is akarma which are the works done without any desire of fruits and giving all the fruits to the lotus feet of lord hari . this gives liberation. the avatars are needed in order to give liberation to the saints,to destroy sinners and to reestablish dharma(gita chapter 4 verse 7 and 8). the only cause for liberation of the jivas is the causeless mercy of lord hari. no one can get liberation by his or her own endeavours. they have to fully surrender to lord hari (gita chapter 18 verse 66)

Comment: You did not answer the question at all!